# Sort Computed Object and Array by Two Fields

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sorting, vuejs2, vuex

I am pulling information from an API that returns data in the following format:

```
[
 {
  "id": 173,
  "date": "2020-12-10T16:05:30",
  "date_gmt": "2020-12-10T16:05:30",
  "guid": {},
  "modified": "2020-12-10T16:05:31",
  "modified_gmt": "2020-12-10T16:05:31",
  "slug": "test",
  "status": "publish",
  "type": "place",
  "link": "http://localhost:81/test/",
  "title": {},
  "content": {},
  "featured_media": 0,
  "template": "",
  "acf": {
    "address": {
    "address": "123 Test Address",
    "street_number": "123",
    "street_name": "Test Address",
    "city": "Philipsburg",
    "state": "Sint Maarten",
    "country": "Sint Maarten",
    "country_short": "SX"
  },
  "header": {}
  },
  "_links": {}
 },
 etc
]
```

I store that in Vuex, and organize the information via the following:

```
computed: {
    resorts() {
      const resorts = {};
      if (this.$store.state.loading === false) {
        this.$store.state.posts.forEach((post) => {
          const c = post.acf.address.country;
          const s = post.acf.address.state;
          //const t = post.title;
          resorts[c] = resorts[c] || {};
          resorts[c][s] = resorts[c][s] || [];
          resorts[c][s].push(post);
        });
      }
      return resorts;
    },
}
```

I'm displaying the information in a `v-for` loop like this (Pug):

```
section.united-states(v-for="(country, index) in resorts" v-if="index==='United States'")
  h1(v-html="index")
  section.state(v-for="(state, subIndex) in country" :key="subIndex" :class="subIndex.toLowerCase()")
    h5(v-html="subIndex")
    ul
      li(v-for="post, resort) in state")
        listing(:id="post.id" :slug="post.slug" :image="post.acf.header" :title="post.title.rendered" :city="post.acf.address.city" :street="post.acf.address.street_name_short")
```

This displays the information correctly. However, I need it organized alphabetically by *Country*, then *State*, then *City* names. I've tried to sort it and attempted `lodash.orderBy`, but could not get the list organized. From the Vue inspector tab in Chrome, the computed countries and states (not cities) appear to be alphabetical. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to sort the posts before grouping them by address.

Using [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`String.prototype.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), create a utility (named `sortPosts()`) to use in the computed prop that will sort the posts by the `country`, `state`, `city`, then `street_name` fields:

```js
const sortPosts = posts =>
  posts.slice().sort((a,b) => {
    const countryA = a.acf.address.country
    const countryB = b.acf.address.country
    const stateA = a.acf.address.state
    const stateB = b.acf.address.state
    const cityA = a.acf.address.city || '' // can be undefined in Google Maps API
    const cityB = b.acf.address.city || '' // can be undefined in Google Maps API
    const streetA = a.acf.address.street_name
    const streetB = b.acf.address.street_name
    return countryA.localeCompare(countryB) || stateA.localeCompare(stateB) || cityA.localeCompare(cityB) || streetA.localeCompare(streetB)
  })
```

Now, we'll group these posts using the same logic you already have, but we have to change the data type of the local `resorts` variable from `Object` to `Map` because [`Object` iteration does not always follow the insertion order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/6277151), which would break the sorting from `sortPosts()`:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    resorts() {
      // BEFORE:
      // const resorts = {};

      const resorts = new Map();

      if (this.$store.state.loading === false) {
        sortPosts(this.$store.state.posts).forEach((post) => {
          const c = post.acf.address.country;
          const s = post.acf.address.state;

          // BEFORE:
          // resorts[c] = resorts[c] || {};
          // resorts[c][s] = resorts[c][s] || [];
          // resorts[c][s].push(post);

          if (!resorts.has(c)) {
            resorts.set(c, new Map());
          }
          const stateMap = resorts.get(c);
          if (!stateMap.has(s)) {
            stateMap.set(s, []);
          }
          stateMap.get(s).push(post);
        });
      }
      return resorts
    },
  }
}
```

As of v2.6.12, `v-for` does not support `Map`s, so use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to make it iterable in `v-for`:

```html
<section v-for="[country, countryData] in Array.from(resorts)" :key="country">
  <h1 v-html="country" />
  <section class="state" v-for="[state, posts] in Array.from(countryData)" :key="state" :class="state.toLowerCase()">
    <h5 v-html="state" />
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(post, resort) in posts" :key="post.id">
        ...
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</section>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sorting-nested-array-data-in-vue-sxe5h?file=/src/components/Demo.vue)